# Prove $|A| = |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A= \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$. Define $B = A − \{a_{n^2} : n \in\mathbb N\}$.
Prove that $|A|=|B|$.

I would say that $B = \{a_2,a_3,a_5,a_6,\ldots\}$. Thus $B$ is a infinite subset of $A$ and since $A$ is denumerable, $B$ is also denumerable. I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Consider when $a_{n^2} := n^2$ and $a_n := 1$ when $n$ is not a square. Or are we implicitly assuming that $a_i \neq a_j$ for $i \neq j$? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much finished. Just remember that $X$ is denumerable if and only if $|X|=|\Bbb N|$, and that equicardinality is an equivalence relation.

---

Another option is to show there is an injection from $A$ into $B$. Then use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: Thus I can say |B| = |N| = |A| right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Without further conditions the statement is wrong as Dustan has already pointed out in a comment. Take for example $a_i=0$ for all $i$, then $|A|=1$, $|B|=0$.

Comment: but B is an infinite subset of A

Comment: Carsten, by definition, sets have no repeated elements. I.e., the cardinality of $A$ just IS the cardinality of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @amWhy, it is true that e.g. $\{0,0,0,\dots\}=\{0\}$, but that does not mean that it is not allowed to write $\{0,0,0,\dots\}$.

Comment: Carsten Methinks you are over-thinking things here.

Comment: @Pasie15, why would you think that?

Comment: @amWhy, if this is the full formulation of the problem, then it is badly written, which is a problem if one expects well formulated answers.

Comment: I do agree with you on that, Carsten.